# Using repeat annotation in Azure Devops

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, nunit

I have a C# Selenium project and I'm using Azure Devops for test run and CI purposes.
In C# I am able to use the `[Repeat(int)]` annotation in order to repeat a specific test.

for instance

```
    [Category("Origin Tests")]
    [Category("Sanity")]
    [Repeat(5)]
    [Test]
    public void _FooTest(){}
```

I'd like to have the ability to configure the repeated number from the Azure Devops pipeline(even by the `yaml` file), but couldn't find a way or even a workaround for that.

Comment: The challenge here, is that the number of repetitions should be a compile-time constant. Which unit test provider are you using?

Comment: The challenge is how to do it in Azure Devops at first time. If it's even possible

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: Nunit & .net core (C#)